# Print Output as it is generated in PHP

Tags: php, python

Here is the pseudo code of what I am doing:

```
<?php
for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++)
{
$result=shell_exec("python code.py");
echo $result;
sleep(15);
}
?>
```

Here is the code.py pseudo code

```
try:
   condition
   print "successful"
except:
   print "not successful"
```

What I am trying to do is, each time the python code is run print its output on the web page instantly, then initiate the sleep timer and repeat.

Instead what I am getting now is the web page stalls for a cumulative 15*5 secs, and displays output of the python code that was run 5 times in one go.

Any suggestions on how this can be done

Comment: are there really no curly brackets involved to that php code? Which lines do you guess will be repeated?

Comment: `for(condition) { // dosomething; sleep(15); }`

Comment: @Jeff There are, I edited the question